# How can change deep fields in redux-form with this.props.change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to change deep fields in `redux-form` with `this.props.change` in `redux-form V6`.

**Here are my `mapStateToProps`:**

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {recipient_type, filters} = 
    formValueSelector('form_wizard')(
    state, 'filters.recipient_type' ,'filters');

    return {
        recipient_type,
        filters
    }
}
```

and here is my `componentDidMount` (where I want to change deep field programmatically)

```js
componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.recipient_type) {
        this.props.change("filters.recipient_type}", someThing);
    }
}
```

The result for `this.props.recipient_type` is undefined.

**Question:**

How can I change the deep field with `this.props.change()` in `redux-form`?

Thanks

Comment: when use redux in your project, change all state need to change with action

Comment: some fields must be changed programmatically. So we can do this by this.props.change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found the Answer

if you want to access the deep field in redux-form you must get it with parent key in  **formValueSelector** :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {filters} = 
    formValueSelector('form_wizard')(
    state, 'filters.recipient_type' );
    return {
        recipient_type : filters,
    }
}
```

and if you need to get parent field:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {filters} = 
    formValueSelector('form_wizard')(
    state, 'filters' );
    return {
        recipient_type : filters.recipient_type,
    }
}
```